# C, autosum code brings up not type int values

Tags: c

The code is very simple, it is just about accepting values from the console and adding them up as I go along, basically an autosum.

My guess on why the code is not working is because somehow it seems that x and y cannot be added together despite both being types int? The code is very simple so I am baffled. If I add say, 4, 3,2,6 I get a weird result looking like 154323432.
I tried other variants such as including all the elements in an array and adding the contents in the subindex, but the result is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void autosuma()  
{

    int x, y =0;
    int i =1;

    while(i <5)  
    {    
        printf("Enter list number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d",&y);
        x = x+y; // I know I could write x=+y;
        i++;  

        printf("%d\n",x);
    }  

    printf("%d",x); // just printing the total
}
```

Comment: To avoid this mistake in the future, you should enable all compiler warnings you can find. And enable optimization, since some warnings depend on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial value of your variable `x` is garbage value, So the every number entered by the user gets added in to that garbage value which will obviously lead to incorrect output.

Initialize your variable `x` to `0`

```
int x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add x=0 at the beginning, everything will be fine.

Comment: Correct Yusaf , thank you and also L2041 I need to wait 5 minutes before they let me accept the answer. Thank you, it worked. Both answers are correct but I have to give it to the first one given, I wish I could accept both.